# How to add this delay to modal open script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal script with id="myBtn"

```
`    <script>
        var datamap = new Map([
            [document.getElementById("myBtn"), document.getElementById("myModal")],
            [document.getElementById("myBtn1"), document.getElementById("myModal1")],
            [document.getElementById("myBtn2"), document.getElementById("myModal2")]
        ]);

        datamap.forEach((value, key) => {
            doModal(key, value);
        });

        function doModal(anchor, popupbox) {

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = popupbox.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            anchor.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                popupbox.style.display = "block";
            });

            span.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                popupbox.style.display = "none";
            });

            window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                if (event.target == popupbox) {
                    popupbox.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>`
```

How would I go about adding the script below I found on this site to the one above.

```
`setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
}, 2000);`
```

I'm trying to make a 3 second fake loader which I have but can't figure out how to add this to the above code. I'm new to this. Could someone edit or add this? Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: Well, on which occassion should the timeout start anyway?

Comment: java is NOT short for JavaScript.

Comment: You found a script for a jQuery UI modal which has NOTHING to do with your code that toggles display. It is unclear how you want that script to work with the code above.

Comment: I want the delay to start after the person clicks on the button or link. I know you shouldn't add JavaScript with links. So basically immediately on clicking, start delay.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry If I offended you. I didn't know.

Comment: All the modals will have a delay if that's what your asking. Immediately after clicking the button / link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a delay with `setTimeout` before setting the display to `block`.

```js
anchor.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    // show the modal after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => popupbox.style.display = "block", 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Unmitigated! =)